# How to merge two mysql results in php?

Tags: php, mysql

As this question clearly means that, I am not asking about `SQL` joins here,

I just want to combine/merge 2 `MySQL` result in `PHP`, i have tried to do it with PHP [array_merge()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) but no success.

```
 $user_paid_query = "SELECT * from users WHERE now_paid!=0 ORDER BY now_paid DESC";
 $result_user_paid = $connect->query($user_paid_query);
 $users_paid = $result_user_paid->fetch_assoc();
 $users_unpaid_query = "SELECT * from users WHERE now_paid=0 ORDER BY id ASC";
 $users = array_merge($users_paid, $users_unpaid);
```

Comment: Why doesn't `array_merge` work? What do your arrays look like? What do you want them to look like after the merge?

Comment: Also note that in the code you have shown, the second query is never executed  / `$users_unpaid` seems to be undefined.

Comment: you don't query the unpaid query. You just attempt to merge it into the other array

Comment: Besides what @jeroen spotted; why don't you just use one query? there's no JOIN needed here. You can do this with a CASE.

Comment: This seems to be a typographical error.

Comment: To add to @FunkFortyNiner's comment, it seems that all you need is `ORDER BY now_paid DESC, id ASC`.

Comment: Btw; any of those past questions solved? Seems like it to me but they're still considered as open/unsolved. Should we be putting in more answers for them?

Comment: @jeroen I had that very same thought; I just didn't write it out ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `union` in MySQL itself(instead of PHP) to merge 2 SQL results.

```
(SELECT * from users WHERE now_paid != 0  ORDER BY now_paid DESC)
UNION
(SELECT * from users WHERE now_paid = 0  ORDER BY id ASC)
```

Comment: @BRO_THOM why? there's only 1 so far and there could be other answers that stand to be just as good.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Why will you want to have extra PHP code when it's possible via query?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner because this solution allows the problem to be solved at a single location, without actually writing code.

Comment: You missed the fact that they never executed the 2nd query. This to me, stands to be all that's wrong with their code. Did you look at all the comments up there @vivek_23 ?

Comment: @BRO_THOM *"This is the only acceptable answer."* - I doubt that there's only "one" solution for this. Sure it's using a single location, but saying what you said isn't entirely true; *think about it* ;-)

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Of course I did read, but what's the point in making the OP settle for a less better way of doing it? Yes, there were bugs in his code, but that doesn't mean you correct them and make him go ahead with that?

Comment: @vivek_23 Don't shoot the messenger *lol!* - But it seems that [Bojan did make a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51655883/how-to-merge-two-mysql-results-in-php#comment90275399_51655883) in regards to the actual post / code they shown us.

Comment: Yes, people discussed about why his code doesn't work, which is fine. But, no one discussed about doing it with a single query except when you pointed about CASE. Hence, I said to let him know about using queries rather than `array_merge()`

Comment: @vivek_23 Yeah, you're right. I was just pointing out what Bojan and Jeroen said/spotted. The OP though, either got their solution (from you) and logged off without marking it as solved, or is being uncooperative. Their track record seems to reflect that.

Comment: A little something for your trouble, and answer ;-) *Cheers*

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Lol thanks a lot ;-) .Also,  I have experienced the same a lot of times on SO. Forget that, I have also experienced some people repeating the same answers on some posts with a bit of minor tweaks, which I call as `stealing the glory.`

Comment: You're welcome @vivek_23 Yeah, I get those also, \**sigh\**. Oh well, "c'est la vie" (I guess). :-)